# How to display an HTML Element if a variable has a certain value in jsx

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am trying to hide/show an element if a variable has a certain value in JSX.

I am new to React and JSX so I am still trying to get my bearings.

My plan is to show a `<p>` tag only if the value of `role` is `admin`

I know that I can display text stored in a variable like this: `<h1>Welcome Back {name}</h1>` and it would display `Welcome back John Doe`. This works fine, but I would like to do something like this:

```js
if ({role} == admin){
  <p> You are an admin</p>
}
else {
  <p>Access denied</p>
}
```

How would I go about getting this to work?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Assume that role is state with dataType string

```
{(role == 'admin')?<p> You are an admin</p>:<p>Access denied</p>}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the ternary operator in the jsx file

With the ternary operator, you can return something conditionally, here the paragraph element

Try:

```
 {role == admin ? <p>You are an admin</p> : <p>Access Denied</p>}
```

How this works is if role is admin then statement after ? is processed otherwise the statement after : is processed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
<p> {role == admin ? "You are an admin" : "Access denied"} </p>
```

This way you can prevent multiple usage of `p` tag and focus on the content inside it.